# Trouble finding highest/lowest element in array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm pretty new to C++, only had experience in C#, Python, and JS so bear with me!

I am taking the user's input on 5 scores and storing it in an array. I pass the array off and evaluate the scores in the array to find the lowest value and highest value. I need to drop those two, then find the average of the other 3 values. My problem is, I'm not finding the highest/lowest value. I have the logic in findLowest() and findHighest() but to test it I put the same logic in main() to see if its working before its passed off, and its not working. Can someone guide me to finding the highest/lowest values in the array? Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void getJudgeData(double score)
{
    cin >> score;
    if (score > 10 || score < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid score, please enter again." << endl;
        cin >> score;
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "Thank you." << endl;
    }
}

double findLowest(double scores[])
{
    double lowScore = *min_element(scores, scores+5);

    return lowScore;
}

double findHighest(double scores[])
{
    double highScore = *max_element(scores, scores+5);

    return highScore;
}
double calcScore(double scores[])
{
    double finalScore;
    double sum = 0;
    double newScore[3] = {};

    double lowScore = findLowest(scores);
    double highScore = findHighest(scores);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (scores[i] != lowScore && scores[i] != highScore)
        {
            scores[i] = newScore[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (int k=0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        sum = sum + newScore[k];
    }
    finalScore = sum/3;
    return finalScore;
}    

int main()          
{
    double finalScore;
    double judgeScores[5] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter judge " << i + 1 << "'s score: ";
        getJudgeData(judgeScores[i]);
    }
    finalScore = calcScore(judgeScores);
    cout << "Highest score is: " << *max_element(judgeScores, judgeScores+5) << endl;
    cout << "The final score is: " << finalScore << endl;

    // This prevents the Console Window from closing during debug mode
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    cout << "\nPress only the 'Enter' key to exit program: ";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to everything else, you are going to have some issues if someone puts in the same score multiple times and it happens to be the highest or lowest score.

Comment: Try using a vector, sorting the vector, removing the highest and lowest elements (the first and last). :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `getJudgeData` takes `double score` by value. As the result, the entries by the end user remain confined to the `getJudgeData` function; the `judgeScores[i]` variable that you pass to the function remains unchanged.

Add an ampersand to fix this problem:

```
void getJudgeData(double &score) {
    ...
}
```

Now the parameter is passed by reference, letting `getJudgeData` make modifications to it.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
void getJudgeData(double score)
```

to

```
void getJudgeData(double &score)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like most of your logic is OK, except you have your assignment swapped in `calcScore()`. You have:

```
scores[i] = newScore[j];
```

You probably meant:

```
newScore[j] = scores[i];
```

Also, be wary: If your input array contains multiple scores equal to the minimum or maximum, you will have less than 3 remaining after you remove them.

*Edit:* Oh yeah, and also what others have said about passing the value by reference to `getJudgeData()`.

Comment: You can either remove them and keep track of the actual number of items you copy to `newScore` (and use that count instead of assuming 3; in your case `j` will be left with the number of items copied [and be careful handling 0 items left]), or you can decide to leave duplicates and only remove one of the lowest and one of the highest (always leaving 3). Up to you, depending on how you want it to behave.